# Does connecting your phone to wifi make it trackable by cellular connection?

Tags: wifi, phone, tracking, cellular

can connecting to wifi reveal my cellular identity ?

So what I mean is say hypothetically the powers that be wanted to tap your cellular phone and your home wifi (having the isp monitor all data). 
And you buy a new phone with a new simcard.

If a brand new phone (with new simcard) connects to a tapped wifi network, does the phone transmit identifying data on the wifi network that could be used to identify it on the cellular network to be able to then tap the new phone/simcard cellular activities after you disconnect from the wifi ?

Comment: You are making quite a few assumptions in your question about the impacts and what's possible. Let's refine it: "if a phone connects to the wifi network, does the phone transmit identifying data on the wifi network that could be used to identify it on the cellular network?" That seems like what you want to know, yes?

Comment: yes indeed thats basicaly what I want to know.

Answer (score 1):

Wifi and cellular data networks use different hardware. One set won't help positively identify the other.

Some data, like MAC, will expose the hardware type (like iPhone, Samsung, etc.) but that's about it.

What will identify you are your actions, not your hardware.